# How to rewrite this eval block

Tags: perl

This code smells... how do I rewrite it better?

```
my $record;

eval {
    while (
        # undef $record here, so if getRecord() failed, nothing will be written
        # in the reject file
        do { undef $record; defined( $record = $dataFile->getRecord ) }
    ) {
        $LT_DataFile->encode($record);
    } 
    1;
};

if ( my $error = $@ ) {
    $rejectFile->writeRecord( $error, $record );
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, reworked my answer.

I think the *REAL* problem here is how you handle the errors.  It's confusing at first glance to see a single error handler when you have multiple places where things could go wrong.  I see two alternatives.

First, keep it mostly the same as you have now, but specifically check for each type of error:

```
my $record;
eval {
    while (defined( $record = $dataFile->getRecord )) {
        $LT_DataFile->encode($record);
    } 
};
if (my $error = $@) {
    given ($error) {
        when (/get record error/) {  $rejectFile->writeRecord($_, undef);   }
        when (/encode error/)     {  $rejectFile->writeRecord($_, $record); }
    }
}
```

This way, you're explicit in how you handle your errors.  Of course, with Try::Tiny, this simplifies into the following

```
my $record;
try {
    while (defined( $record = $dataFile->getRecord )) {
        $LT_DataFile->encode($record);
    } 
} catch {
    when (/get record error/) {  $rejectFile->writeRecord($_, undef);   }
    when (/encode error/)     {  $rejectFile->writeRecord($_, $record); }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the lexical record per [Daxim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067585/how-to-rewrite-this-eval-block/3067965#3067965).  This requires a second eval or try, closer to the problem and adding a `last` call:

```
eval {
    while (defined( my $record = $dataFile->getRecord )) {
        eval { $LT_DataFile->encode($record) };
        if (my $error = $@) { $rejectFile->writeRecord($error, $record); last }
    } 
};
if (my $error = $@) {
    $rejectFile->writeRecord($error, undef);
}
```

Unfortunately this method won't work with Try::Tiny, because the blocks passed to try are actually subrefs.

Comment: But you've ignored the comment explaining why `$record` needs to be `undef`.  If `getRecord` throws an error, you'll be reporting the previous (non-erroneous) record.

Comment: And now you have the opposite problem.  If `encode` throws an error, you'll be reporting `undef` instead of the record that caused the error.

Comment: Damn, it was confusing code.  Cleaned up in its entirety now.

Comment: If this were my code, I'd write unit tests that exercised every code path.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need a variable in the catch part because when execution arrives there its content will always be `undef`. Replacing this with a literal value lets us restrict `$record` to a smaller scope.

```
use Try::Tiny;
try {
    while (defined(my $record = $dataFile->getRecord)) {
        $LT_DataFile->encode($record);
    }
} catch {
    $rejectFile->writeRecord($_, undef);    # T::T puts error in $_
}
```

Comment: +1 for Try::Tiny. To @est, doing the `eval` and then separately testing `$@` can cause problems (missed errors, incorrect error messages) in some cases due to `$@` being global. Use Try::Tiny instead because it handles all those details for you.

Comment: Why do you say `$record` would always be `undef` if there's an error?  Presumably the `encode` method is capable of throwing errors, and in that case `$record` would be the record that caused the encoding error.  It's only `undef` if `getRecord` is the method that failed.

Comment: If $record is an object, then you can drop the `defined`, and just check for truthiness: `while (my $record = ...)) }`

Comment: @Ether: Remember that objects can overload `bool`, so a defined object can evaluate to false.  (Or, if the object overloads conversion to string or number, those will be used to determine truthiness.)

Comment: @cjm: objects *could*, but one would hope that they would do so intelligently and return a logical result -- e.g. a defined object evaluating to false in a boolean context could indicate an invalid or corrupt dataset, so checking this value might do exactly what the caller needs.

Comment: +1 for @cjm, encode() still needs to capture the $record when it throws exception. The solution from Robert P below works the best for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor the `while` loop to

```
while (defined( $record = $dataFile->getRecord )) {
    $LT_DataFile->encode($record);
} continue {
    undef $record;
}
```

The `continue` block is executed after each iteration before conditional is tested. It will still be called if your code uses `next` to start the next iteration early. If your not likely to call `next` then simplifying the code to

```
while (defined( $record = $dataFile->getRecord )) {
    $LT_DataFile->encode($record);
    undef $record;
}
```

would work as well.

Comment: This will not work as expected.... when $dataFile->getRecord() throws exception, $record already has value from previous iteration, so $rejectFile->writeRecord() gets the wrong information.

Comment: @est how so? The call do `undef $record;` will always be called before the conditional in the next iteration of the loop. If `$dataFile->getRecord()` dies then `$record` is undef. Any action that will skip the `continue` block will either end the loop or skip the conditional. Assuming that `$record` is not defined before the first iteration then `$record` will always be undefined when `$dataFile->getRecord` is called and always defined when `$LT_DataFile->encode($record);` is called.